# Дружественные методы класса: в чем ошибка в данном примере?

Tags: c++

В данном примере есть метод Array::calc, который является дружественным классу Matrix. При этом здесь происходит что-то странное. Почему-то выражение _array[i] выдает рандомное значение, а не i-й элемент массива. При этом в других функциях все нормально. В чем здесь ошибка?
Полный листинг: http://pastebin.com/x3p2M80v

```
class Array {
      private:
              int _size;
              int * _array;

      public:
             friend void print(Array arr);
             int calc(int &count, Matrix matr);

      Array (int size) {
            _size = size;

            _array = new int [_size];

            };

      ~Array() {

               delete [] _array;

               };
      void Initializer (int array[]) {

           for (int i=0; i<_size; i++) {

               _array[i] = array[i];

               }

           };

      };

int Array::calc(int &count, Matrix matr) {

                  int arrcount = 0;
                  int matrcount = 0;

                  for (int i=0; i<_size; i++) {

                      if (_array[i]<0)

                         arrcount ++;

                      }

                  for (int i=0; i<matr._rows; i++) {

                      for (int j=0; j<matr._cols; j++) {

                          if (matr._matrix[i][j] < 0)

                          matrcount ++;

                          }

                      }
                      int here;

                      if (arrcount>matrcount) {
                         here = 1;
                         count = arrcount-matrcount;
                         }
                      else if (arrcount<matrcount) {
                           here = -1;
                           count = matrcount-arrcount;
                           }
                           else {
                                here = 0;
                                count = 0;
                                }
                           return here;
                  }
```

Comment: А вы не могли бы уменьшить пример до минимально необходимого? А то лень в такой большой простыне кода разбираться, если честно.

Comment: Уменьшил до минимального

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый совет на будущее - Вы знаете место, где _array разрушается - это деструктор `Array`. Если возникает такая ситуация, то поставьте туда точку останова и посмотрите когда она срабатывает. Так, за 1.5 минуты, я понял в чём проблема.

У Вас классическая проблема, когда не переопределён `copy ctor`, 1000 раз описанная во всевозможных учебниках по С++ в теме "почему важно иметь правильный конструктор копирования". В строке 185 - `print ( arra);` создаётся временная копия объекта `Array`, по завершению функции `print` этот объект будет разрушен, у него будет вызван деструктор, который очистит память, занимаемую `_array`. Т.к. copy ctor у Вас не определён, то фактически будет очищена память, которая используется оригинальным объектом. Чтобы решить эту проблему нужно или написать правильный `copy ctor`, который выделит память и скопирует туда содержимое копируемого объекта, или изменить сигнатуру `print(const Array&)`. Но самое правильное решение это сделать и то, и другое.

Comment: Поскольку массив — потенциально большая штука, лучше конструктор копирования сделать приватным, чтобы никто не копировал `Array`, а передавал по ссылке.

Comment: Черт, как же ж я это проглядел. В программировании стаж большой, а на такой тупой фигне лажанулся :) И ведь сразу же подумал, что в копирующем конструкторе дело может быть, но почему то отбросил эту мысль...

Большое спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Классика крестов. 

Сначала создаем себе проблемы, а потом героически   преодолеваем  их.

Не пишите на С++.